# Multiple Timer Job in the same SharePoint famr solution project shows up with the same Title in Central Admin Job Definiation

Tags: development, timer-jobs

I have a SharePoint farm solution in VS2013 for SharePoint 2013.  It contains two timer jobs, and each has their own feature definition.  Once it has deployed to the development SharePoint server locally, both jobs are showing with the same title in Job Definition.

In the event receiver of each feature definition, in FeatureActivated, I have created a new Job with a different name in code.

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1):

multiple jobs showed in the Jobs defination or multiple jobs run?
usually multiple jobs due to more than one content DB in a web App. so if you have morethan one content db then timer job will run multiple time.
alos check my [response here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c8f513ed-7ee8-4ce6-b686-af8e7f145373/multiple-timer-jobs-executing-upon-new-database?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious),i mentioned how to prevent the custom jobs to run multiple time.

Comment: I have one content DB.  It shows two entries with the same title in "Jobs Definition" and they have different schedule just like how I have specified in the FeatureReceiver.  I have checked both FeatureReceiver, they have different GUID and I have very sure I have passed a different name when I create the Job in code.

Comment: how many webapp you have and how many servers in farm?

Comment: One webapp and one server

Comment: did you go through this blog post: http://blog.rafelo.com/2009/04/10/sharepoint-timer-jobs-running-multiple-times/

Comment: It is not one Timer Job runs multiple times, my problems is two Timer Job listed with the same name, and their schedule are exactly like how I set them up in visual studio, but their name should not be the same.  Screen shot from Job Definition: https://app.box.com/s/s6vklm2550dool65c41z